# Regex to not split string on [ if it comes under " "

Tags: java, regex, string

I am looking to split my string on basis of [, ]. But there is one restriction, if the [, ]  comes within " ", we should ignore them .

Example :

For a string:

```
"""hello "hi" [abc: "pqr[abc]"] bye | [xyz]"""
```

the splitted strings should be :

```
hello "hi"
abc: "pqr[abc]"
bye |
xyz
```

Comment: Split on `[` `,` `space` `]` ?

Comment: Which programming language? `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` comes to my mind.

Comment: It is for JAVA @Jan

Comment: @Rahul: That will not work. When you split on [, even those inside " will get split.

Comment: Where did that extra space come from in the result (between "bye" and "xyz")?

Comment: I am asking exactly which characters to split on ?

Comment: @Rahul : on [ and ] only.

Comment: Why is `bye |` not split into two parts?

Comment: @trincot: Because we are splitting only on [ and ] and not on space.

Comment: Then why is `hello "hi"` split into two parts?

Comment: @trincot: Corrected that. my bad! Sorry.

Comment: Do you need a single pass/regex? You might go through and replace the quoted brackets with something, and then split on the brackets, then put the quoted brackets back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to split, you can use the `find()` method and describe all that isn't a square bracket except for parts between quotes:

```
[^\]\["]+(?:"[^"]*"[^\]\["]*)*|(?:"[^"]*"[^\]\["]*)+
```

(Dont't forget to add backslashes in your pattern string.)

[demo](http://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyyyp3y8yr)

Answer (score 1):

One of possible solutions (which doesn't require tricky regexps) might be as follows:

(1) split without regard to quotes

(2) count (cumulative) numbers of quotes at each resulting component

(3) re-join at boundaries where such a number is odd

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to split, then you can use look-ahead to check that the number of quotes that follows the candidate delimiter is even:

[`[\][](?=[^"]*(?:"[^"]*"[^"]*)*$)`](https://regex101.com/r/gEfdbC/2)

But look-ahead is quite inefficient. If it is acceptable to do the opposite and find the matches *between* the delimiters (with `find()`), instead of splitting, then you can use:

[`(?:[^"\][]|"[^"]*")+`](https://regex101.com/r/gEfdbC/1)